# Почему не видит изображение в image.src

Tags: javascript, html

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('Sprite');
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 100;

let coinImage = new Image();
coinImage.src = 'photo/sprite.png';

let sprite = new Sprite({
    ctx: canvas.getContext('2d'),
    image: coinImage,
    width: 1000,
    height: 100,
    numberOfFrames: 10,
    ticksPerFrame: 4,
})
```

Имеется такой код, хочу отобразить часть спрайта, но почему то не видит это изображение(пробовал и абсолютный путь). Если же изображение загрузить и получить ссылку на него через хостинг, то сразу видит, в чем проблема?

Comment: проблема нет. так работает веб

Comment: То есть чтобы загрузить спрайт необходимо сначала через хостинги получить ссылку на него?

Comment: Приблизительно так. Если вы запускаете веб-сервер локально, то адрес нужно указывать относительно хоста.